# Получение хэшей похожих видео

Tags: машинное-обучение, информатика

Интересны решения для задачи сравнения хэшей видео. Т.е. есть одно исходное видео, которое можно заранее как угодно проиндексировать. И есть набор неиндексированных видео, которые представляют копии исходного с возможными вырезанными фрагментами (набор кадров, который существенно меньше исходного видео), маловероятно, но может быть перестановка фрагментов, удаление отдельных кадров, незначительное изменение кадров (наложение водяных знаков, обрезка, искажение, размытие и т.п.). Какие существуют решения под такие задачи. Важна скорость обработки особенно неиндексированных видео. Как такой класс задач называется?

Comment: Поищите какие-нибудь статьи тут https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=ru&as_sdt=0%2C5&as_ylo=2016&q=video+similarity. Вот, например, есть реализация модели https://github.com/MKLab-ITI/visil. Совсем не факт, что это подойдёт вам. Ещё наверно, вам стоит использовать какой-нибудь Scene Change Detector, чтобы поделить видео на куски со схожими кадрами.

Comment: @КириллМалышев если накидаете ключевых слов, будет круто. Спасибо за ссыль. paperwithcode тогда уж (=

Comment: На ум пришел "перцептивный хэш", но это наверное совсем не в тему(

Comment: возможно пригодится https://habr.com/ru/company/wunderfund/blog/275043/, я думаю нужно детектировать контуры движения (https://myrusakov.ru/python-opencv-move-detection.html) и возможно гистограммы кадров (если цветокоррекция маловероятно, хотя по синему каналу думаю она будет почти не заметна) высчитывать из этого получать хэш и уже с ним работать

Comment: если кадры не изменялись, можно просчитать crc32-хэш каждого кадра. Потом посчитать процент совпавших хэшей.

Comment: @DiD не изменялись -- это как?

Comment: @DaniilLoban спасибо за идею. Кажется, клёвой